# how to disable jquery sort on a content_tag_for element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

i'm sorting a list of items using jquery ui sortable like so:

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs.nav-stacked#lineup{"data-update-url" => sort_lineups_url}
  - @pieces.each_with_index do |piece, index|
    = content_tag_for :li, piece do
      = link_to "#{(index + 1).to_s + ' - ' + piece.name}", '#'

jQuery ->
  $('#lineup').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  );
  $( "#not-sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

what I want to do is always disable the first item in @pieces from being sorted. however, I can't figure out quite how to do this using disableSelection(). please help.

Answer (score 0):

`disableSelection` only keeps text from being selected; it doesn't stop an element from being `sortable`.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jquery-ui/B2h_Ea4jo5I.

The best way to achieve this is by using the [cancel option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-cancel).

Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/s6XTu/7/

Comment: i tried this and it worked but i want to make it so the first element cannot be moved by another element...meaning it is always the first position and there's no way to put another above it.